# pyplot: Can I set a global marker size parameter?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a command I can use to globally set the size of all scatter plot points, throughout my program?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can [define your own stylesheet](http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html) or[override the defaults by hand](http://geeksta.net/geeklog/custom-matplotlib-styles/)

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['lines.markersize'] = 10
```

And [here are the default styles](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib/)

Comment: See [default matplotlibrc](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/f6e0ee49c598f59c6e6cf4eefe473e4dc634a58a/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc) for options.